# C++ and designing an OO class

Tags: c++, oop, boost

I am fairly new to C++ and especially object-oriented design of classes.
I want to design a router class that would support the following:

The main area I’m asking for guidance on below is how design to the class(es) and Router class methods that spin off the host and listener threads in a way that facilitates establishing linkage between host and clients.  The host class and client class will have their own write methods.

Currently I have a host class, client class and a client listener class.
The host will run on its own thread and have a unique socket.
The client listener will run on its own thread, and kick off instances of the client class each with its own socket as clients connect. The client listener thread will only start after the host thread connects.

Any message received from the host would either: 
1)  get routed to all clients
2)  get routed to specific client(s) based on key information in the message. A key to socket table will be maintained.

Any message received from a client will unconditionally get routed (written to) the host socket. A phase II would implement support for multiple hosts with a corresponding scheme dealing with which host to route to. Also, I am using boost::asio for the communications.

Any help would be appreciated. If this seems too elementary for some of you, please
forgive me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could use a class named something like `HostToClientMapper`, which would maintain the maps to get all the clients for a host and vice versa. This class could be a member of `Router`. Then Router would have all that's necessary to do its mappings.

Comment: Okay, but thing I am unclear on how to do is how would I get access to the socket information created in the spun off threads. The host socket and any client connections established by the client listener thread. Or put another way, if I have a member in a class that starts a thread, how do I return the this pointer to the class?

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for a way to send data from your Client threads back to the Router? If so, a simple way would be to pass a pointer to the Router instance to the Client objects you create, e.g. Client c = new Client(this). Then in Router you could have a method to set the socket, e.g. Router:setSocket(Client c, Socket s). Make sure you synchronize access to the router's data structures with a mutex, to prevent concurrent modification by the client threads.

Comment: Client threads to send data to the host thread(socket) and vice versa.

Comment: You can either use synchronized shared memory (like in my comment above), or send messages between threads (if you use a framework that supports that, e.g. Qt or Boost)...